# How can I make an athena query on s3 bucket containing .db (sql database) file format?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have a file on s3 bucket of size 4g containing SQL database with file format (.db). what should I do to use athena query on it as there is no .db file format on athen query ? or should I use an another service ?

Answer (score 0):

Athena primarily supports querying structured data in formats like Parquet, ORC, JSON, CSV, and other columnar formats. It doesn't support querying SQLite databases in the .db file format.

Solution 1: Convert your files to a format supported by Athena

Solution 2: Use an EC2 instance to host your own SQLite database instance and run queries directly there.